# Suspicion: Can't write any files in Vscode workspaces (windows + Vscode + git)

Tags: windows, git, github, visual-studio-code

now I already opened a question to this, it was about simple fopen/fwrite of stdio.h ops failing to create and write any file.

I found out that the ops work, when the path is not in a workspace folder, otherwise the c programm exited with file not found  perror, errno == 0x2.

For me, changing paths to write, was the solution for the old problem - however now i'm writing simple javacode, that I can't compile,

getting the following error:  bla bla "..error: error while writing Calculator:.." + blabla

when compiling.

I tried to create a file with New-Item in Powershell(as admin) it terminated with a

" WriteError: (C:\Users\xyza...or\icreated.txt:String) [New-Item], FileNotFoundException"

The same thing with echo "blablaa" >> icreated.txt

which all looks suspicious to me.

It could be either that git is doing something i don't understand, setting up write restriction, or vscode does it.

If it s vscode, then it s probably because of the vscode extensions, I use:

like C/C++ Extension Pack,

GitLens,

Github Theme,

Github Repositories,

IntelliCode API Usage Examples

Java Language Support

Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat

Fix Checksums etc.

To me it seems that Vscode is really blocking any write or creation attempt (from outside like with powershell (even when shell opened by vscode)),

while vscode itself can create files.

One important detail is, that when I compiled C files which outputs inside a vs-code workspace folder, it does work, even while vscode running. So this may be java-specific.

Any solutions ?

I'm thankful for every answer.

RNNUser

add:
tried to create files, write files, and compiled different languages.

C - Files can compile, however file options which hardcode paths to vscode workspaces don't work.